# How to parse nested Objects?

Tags: oop

When there are nested objects, I am currently parsing it as object1.object2.object3.. and so on. However, this trouble some. Is there any design pattern or a better way to deal with nested objects.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask], and [edit] your question accordingly. Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, probably the visitor pattern might work for your case. you could take a look at the link. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/visitor_pattern.htm